# Is there a software which can amplify the sound?

Tags: linux, music, ubuntu, audio

Is possible to amplify the system sound with software, without losing sound quality?I want it for videos and,especially,for listening to music.
What programs for Ubuntu 12.04 can do this?

Comment: For what use case do you need this? Many audio tools ship their own set of amplifiers so if you want to listen to music / watch video the answers will be very different to if you want to play games and have your teamspeak amplified. Please do provide more detail on what you do and how you would want to change it.

Comment: I want to listen to music and watch videos,but especially for music.I wish this helps...

Comment: Please do edit this into your question. You find the edit link below the question, above the comments. The more precisely you describe what you do and what you want the better the answers will be. Have a read of this meta discussion to see how you can improve your question and get better answers: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information Enjoy your stay.

Comment: Please edit your question to state all of your requirements. You [already tried Pulseaudio volume control and found it unsatisfactory](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/is-there-a-software-which-can-amplify-the-sound#comment4676_2333) — so you need to mention that in your question, and explain why it isn't suitable! By not doing this, you're wasting our time finding suggestions that don't help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sound server [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) (aka. pavucontrol and previously known as Polypaudio):

- free
- run on Ubuntu (KDE/Gnome)
- amplify the sound (default max boost: ~150%)
- however the higher the amplification, the more distorted the sound will be

[image]

FYI if you want to go over the default max boost (~150%): see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/219739/44876).

Comment: I already tried it,but I want the best quality ever!

Comment: Can you please add in your question which applications you tried, and what's the best you've found so far?