# Movie player where volume can be increased over 100%

Tags: linux, media-player

This question seems so easy to answer, but it's very hard! I'm on Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit. VLC crashes every time. Until that issue is fixed, I'm looking for an alternative. I have only 2 requirements, and the second one is the one that's tricky.

I have an HP Pavillion G6. When I used windows, the speakers were 'okay'. On Linux, the sound is significantly lower (the volume, not quality)(I have tried many Linux distros over the years). When I watch movies, I have to use VLC and go to 200% volume.

Now that VLC doesn't work anymore, I want a movie player that can...

- play popular movie formats
- increase the volume up beyond traditional movie players, so high, just like vlc.

I've tried many. Parole, Gnome player, etc..., but none have the second feature. The second feature is what I'm looking for and is what's so hard to find.

Comment: Regarding point 2, how about [PulseAudio](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2333/903)?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt wonderful! I had pulseaudio server by default, didn't have the client, just installed it and now the sound is that much better, I immediately upvoted your answer there, you solved two questions :) this is the first one and the second one is this http://askubuntu.com/questions/457976/are-there-better-sound-drivers-for-my-sound-card

Comment: Glad it was useful. I added PulseAudio here as an answer as the other question got closed and comments are sometimes cleaned :)

Comment: *VLC is gone* - you scared me for a second there, you made me think that VLC is no longer developed.

Comment: @André hehe I meant it's gone from my pc :)

Comment: AFAIR, [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) should be capable of doing so; and it plays a lot of formats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use any video player and  increase the volume up using the sound server [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) (aka. pavucontrol and previously known as Polypaudio):

- free
- run on Ubuntu (KDE/Gnome)
- amplify the sound (default max boost: ~150%)
- however the higher the amplification, the more distorted the sound will be

[image]

FYI if you want to go over the default max boost (~150%): see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/219739/44876).

Answer (score 0):

[VLC Media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) allows you to boost audio to 200%. As a media player, it can play most of the movie and audio formats that you throw at it without the need of any extra codecs.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that vlc crashes on my system so this answer is useless to me as long as this issue isn't fixed http://askubuntu.com/questions/457966/vlc-crashes-on-xubuntu-14-04